# How to send request of mongoose documents in each period of time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to send mongoose documents in period of time. Let assume mongoose document as follows :

```
[
{ _id : X, name, surname, image,created_at},
{ _id : Y, name, surname, image,created_at},
{ _id : Z, name, surname, image,created_at},
{ _id : Q, name, surname, image,created_at}, 
]
```

What I need is if all clients send request now, I need to send documents X and Y and after 5 second I need to send Z and Q. After 5 seconds it needs to repeat to send X and Y again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is using pagination, time for last request attempted, time of server started. The code below :

```
 class DiscoverHandler {
  constructor(model) {
    this.time = Date.now()
    this.model = model;
    this.page = 1;
    this.perPageTime = 5000; // ms
    this.maxPage = Infinity
  }
  paginateHandler() {
    const now = Date.now();
    const difference = now - this.time;
    const pageStep = Number((difference / this.perPageTime).toFixed(0))
    if (difference >= this.perPageTime) {
      this.nextPage(pageStep)
    }
  }
  nextPage(pageStep = 1) {
    if (this.page + pageStep > this.maxPage) {
      this.page = pageStep;
    }
    else {
      this.page = this.page + pageStep;
    }
    this.time = Date.now()
  }

  async getData(query, options = {}) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      this.paginateHandler();
      const data = await this.model.paginate({}, {
        page: this.page,
        limit: 2,
        ...options
      }
      )
      if (data) {
        this.maxPage = data.totalPages
        resolve(data.docs)
      }
      else {
        resolve("error getting")
      }
    })
  }
  async sendResponse(res, query = {}) {


    res.send({ data: await this.getData(query) })
  }



}
module.exports = DiscoverHandler;
```